# Two scale problems books

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is not technically a question but more of a help , I need some books to help me go into the theory of two scales and their applications in Partial differential equations.

Comment: It is a request for references (books), but more context would improve the Question. What motivated your request for such books?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to [Two-Scale Convergence of Allaire](https://hal.science/hal-01111805/document) I can recommend [Multiscale Methods: Averaging and Homogenization by Stuart and Pavliotis.](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-73829-1)